# MySQL: Index on Order By with range Where clause

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Before I rewrite my query and code etc. etc., just want to verify that...

Is it true that there is no way to create an index, or rewrite the query below, in such a way that the index is used to filter on date (which is a range or set of dates) AND used to sort on price? If it is possible, how?

```
select id 
from my_table
where  date in ('2013-02-13', '2013-02-14' )
order by price;
```

My problem is that the date filter might actually return lots (> 100,000) rows and I need these sorted by price.

Comment: [Can MySQL use index in a RANGE QUERY with ORDER BY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083632/can-mysql-use-index-in-a-range-query-with-order-by)

Comment: Is it an option for you to use a BETWEEN in your where clause instead of IN or do you plan on skipping dates?