# SQL use a two column index or two single indexes ( x = ? and y > ?)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This question might seem very similar to previous posted ones but slightly different. 
When your queries always contains both columns I know it is a good practice to create an index for both column but for this scenario the queries will be like checking for a column and then finding all records greater than a given value from the second column, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE User_Id = 'Johndoe' AND Last_Query > 1001
```

So should I still use a single index for both Columns (`User_id`, `Last_Query` in the above example) or should I make different indices for each columns?

Comment: Sometimes you shouldn't use an index at all.  A lot of it depends on the size of the table and the type of data.

Comment: Should use indexes on this one, this will be a big table holding a many to many relationship so for each user at a given point will need to see any new question posted for him @vol7ron

Comment: One index for User_Id would be sufficient since you're applying where 'User_Id' (index used) AND Last_Query > 1001 (Index not used)

Comment: Will you ever be searching by either field individually?  Does that query need to be performant?

Comment: Then you should include both the columns in your index if they both are used in where clause ..if you leave one optimiser may not use the index at all.

Comment: @vol7ron yeah query needs to be performant, and it will be used with the above query, one column with equality and second one with a range, always both columns though not equality conditionals on both.  From what I've been reading separate index should be better to use both indexes and equality first of course then ranges ones.

Comment: No.. will the individual field lookup query need to be performant, if you ever do that?  Will you ever look up just user_id or just last_query?  If not, then use the multi-column.  Note that if you do (user_id, last_query), the index will still be used if you only wanted to look up user_id or user_id+last_query.  The index would not be used if you only looked up last_query.  Yes equality first, but it also depends on your data.  If your entire table has mostly 'Johndoe' for user_id, then no, it wouldn't be.  You want to be as restrictive as possible in your where statement.

Comment: @vol7ron I understand if only one of the columns is used on the where then the multiIndex is useless, I will always include both columns on the query, just that it won't be using equality conditionals ( user_id = ? and last_query = ?)  but with the range ( user_id = ? and last_query > ?), so my question is whether the multi column index will still be used when using that conditionals ( =  and > )

Comment: No it's not useless, but the order of the multicolumn matters for when you want to use a partial index.  Regarding your range, it doesn't have much affect other than performance.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083632/can-mysql-use-index-in-a-range-query-with-order-by which asks the same question

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved, especially when it comes to areas where the products may behave differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multicolumn indexes are designed to handle exactly this case.  When the first column in an index has a value that is known (User_Id = 'Johndoe' in your example), all the rows with that value are ordered by the second column in the index (Last_Query in your example).  This allows for efficient seeking to where the range on the second column starts.

In general, this works when any prefix of the index columns have "=" filters on them followed by a range filter (> or <) on the next index column. i.e, an index on (col1, ..., colN+1) and a WHERE filter such as:

```
WHERE col1=a AND col2=b ... AND colN=c AND colN+1 > d
```